# How to make jquery fadeTo() animate on behind when showing confirm() popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to ask how to make fadeout when showing confirm()
When I clicked delete The box will fadeOut to 0.5 opacity slowly, when on confirmation to delete or not to delete.
But the slowly fading not occuring.

Here is the code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".animate-fade").click(function(e){
        $("#div1").fadeTo("slow", 0.15);
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").fadeTo("slow", 0.15);
var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
    });
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<p>The box didnt animate the fade effect when confirm() popup shown how to make it animated?</p>

<button>Delete Boxes</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button class='animate-fade'>Animate fade</button><br><br>

<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of callback :

```
$("button").click(function(){

    $("#div1").fadeTo("slow", 0.15,function() {

        var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
    })
})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<p>The box didnt animate the fade effect when confirm() popup shown how to make it animated?</p>

<button>Delete Boxes</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button class='animate-fade'>Animate fade</button><br><br>

<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;"></div>

</body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".animate-fade").click(function(e){
        $("#div1").fadeTo("slow", 0.15);
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
    $("button").click(function(){
        
        $("#div1").fadeTo("slow", 0.15,function() {
            
            var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
        })
        
    })
  
});
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`fadeTo()` animation is async while  `window.confirm` is modal, it freezes any running javascript code.  Depending your exact expected behaviour, you should set your confirm box when the animation completes:

```
$("#div1").fadeTo("slow", 0.15, function() {
   var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
   /* do whatever with answer variable*/
 });
```

An other way if you want the effect to be simultanous would be to use CSS transition/animation and just put the `confirm()` in event queue using a timeout.

Here are an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/3zf4917s/1/)

Comment: Thx for the second example sir :D